# Websockets (Socket.io) and authentication/authorization

Tags: ajax, http, authentication, authorization, socket.io

I'm giving socket.io a whirl and I'm curious as to what I should and shouldn't be doing with websockets.

For example is there a way to authenticate a websocket (include id in every message perhaps?)? Let's say I'm creating a 'google docs' like app in which people can create new documents. Should I be using AJAX to create new documents instead of websockets? That way I can use the standard HTTP transport layer to do all of the user authorization (checking session, etc) and then simply ping back the page with a websocket event. Curious as to how people handle situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using AJAX wherever you do not absolutely need web sockets.  Web sockets end up creating more load on the server side (socket.io will take care of fallbacks in case web sockets & flash sockets are not available).  In short, use web sockets where you need to maintain that state/connection to the client.

If you wish to use web sockets, using cookies with socket.io would be one approach that would allow you to keep track of your sessions.  If not using socket.io right away, you can send req.sessionID (key) to the client, store the session information in Redis/Mongo etc.  When the socket.io connection is attempted, read the cookie value & send it to the server - where you can get the session store information.  There may be issues if you use flash sockets as one of the fallbacks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the tips on cookies + socket.io. It's an internal real time app so fallbacks aren't much of an issue